# Web Based Document Viewer Including Office Formats

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for a web based way of showing users tiff, pdf, doc(x), and xls(x) files. This is being required from a business standpoint and I don't have a whole lot of weight/control into the decision being made. The web application will be used by both internal and external customers, not publically available though.

Pricing is not such a big deal right now, the active stakeholders know this is extremely valuable and important. So to a point, pricing does not matter.

I was hoping somebody else's google-fu was better than mine, or knows of a good solution/product that doesn't necessarily have good search engine ranking.

#### Little more info

I do believe all we will need is a way to view the images. We will not be performing any redaction or annotations. It would be nice to have a thumbnail control to facilitate flipping through many pages (upwards around 100), but this is not required. There will be other controls on the page, so I'm looking for a minimalistic viewer. Being able to customize the navigation buttons/controls would be an added bonus as well. Also this will be developed/deployed using ASP.NET MVC2 on an IIS7 x64 platform.

A silverlight/flash control/solution would also be acceptable.

#### Current Findings

- [Previewing TIF documents on the Web (.Net C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939221/previewing-tif-documents-on-the-web-net-c) - Only directed at TIF images
- http://www.accusoft.com/prizmviewerfeatures.htm - uses a browser plugin. This is not ideal, but a possibility.
- http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage - Does not seem to support MSFT Office formats, no mention of MVC support.
- http://www.snowbound.com/viewer_inaction/viewerdemos.html - So far this one is coming out ahead, it supports many formats (pay for the formats you need/want). But again, no mention of MVC.
- Google Docs API - From what I can tell in order to use Google's conversion, you need to put the documents on their server. This will not work for us because of sensitive information the documents have.

Comment: i have the same  problem, what solution you have apply.

Answer (score 1):

There's a partial solution for this that involves converting the various documents into HTML for display (or any other web-capable format) in a web browser.  It doesn't satisfy all your requirements but may lead to something useful eventually.

[JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) offers a server-side java-based solution that leverages OpenOffice.org's powerful converter to convert from any supported format to any other supported format.

From the website:

> JODConverter, the Java OpenDocument
>   Converter, converts documents between
>   different office formats. It leverages
>   OpenOffice.org, which provides
>   arguably the best import/export
>   filters for OpenDocument and Microsoft
>   Office formats available today

I've [used it successfully](http://scribblesquid.com) to convert documents from MSWord to HTML for display in the browser.  Any format that OpenOffice supports is supported by JODConverter.  So PDF, MS formats, TIFF and others are supported.

It's java so it's platform independent - I've used it on a Windows, Mac and Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of other ones I have found:

http://www.eviewer.net : An HTML5 based viewer that has both .NET and Java backend.

http://www.ms-technology.com/viewing-solutions : They have Java Applet, Silverlight, Flash viewers that would fulfill your needs as well.

I hope this helps.